# Exception with Regular Expression for WordPress

Tags: regex, wordpress, security, .htaccess

The regular expression `^/wp-[^./]+\.php$` matches:

- wp-config.php

  wp-commentsrss2.php

  wp-pass.php

  wp-rdf.php

  [...]

But I need another regex which matches all above except wp-login.php.

Is it possible to define an exception within that regular expression? How?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^/wp-((?!login)[^./]+)\.php$
```

You can read about Negative Lookahead [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `^/wp-((?!login).+)\.php$`

That'll match everything that starts with `/wp-` and ends with `.php` but not `/wp-login.php`.